# FCM + Nodejs IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#use-credentials-to-mint-access-tokens

I want to send Fcm message in my Nodejs server

I already test it in postman

It's working

[image]

**But in Nodejs
return Body bring error**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/undefined' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "cloudmessaging.messages.create",
          "resource": "projects/undefined"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the code that get accessToken and send FCMmessage

What problem with me?
What does error message mean?

```
function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    
    const jwtClient = new googleAuth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'],
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
}

  var PROJECT_ID = key.PROJECT_ID;
  var HOST = 'fcm.googleapis.com';
  var PATH = '/v1/projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/messages:send';

function sendFcmMessage(fcmMessage) { 
  getAccessToken().then(function(accessToken) { 
      var options = { 
          hostname: HOST, 
          path: PATH, 
          method: 'POST', 
          headers: { 
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      }; 
      var request = https.request(options, function(resp) { 
          resp.setEncoding('utf8'); 
          resp.on('data', function(data) { 
              console.log(accessToken);
              console.log('Firebase Message');
              console.log(data); 
          });
      }); 
      request.on('error', function(err) { 
          console.log('Firebase error'); 
          console.log(err); 
      }); 
      request.write(JSON.stringify(fcmMessage)); 
      request.end(); 
  }); 
}
```